# 404 on non root '/' NginX location

Tags: nginx

I have a text file that is served fine from the root `/hi.txt` URL but not from a `/test/hi.txt` URL.

Here is the full NginX configuration:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xxx.com *.xxx.com;
    server_tokens off;

    root /var/www/certbot;

    location /test {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I would like to have the file not 404 on the `http://example.com/test/hi.txt` request.

UPDATE II: I now understand more on the issue. The error log shows:

```
open() "/var/www/certbot/test/hi.txt" failed (2: No such file or directory),
```

I thought the `/test` location was NOT suffixed to the root.

Is there any way NOT to suffix the `/test` location ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an alias here, like:

```
location /test {
        alias /var/www/certbot;
}
```

See here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias

Comment: I just saw your answer after I posted mine. For the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Using an `alias` and not having any trailing slash `/` character in the location path, had the file served fine:

```
location /test {
    alias /var/www/certbot;
}
```